# How to open new view from collection view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to iOS and struggling in opening new view controller from collection view.

Can anyone help me in how to open new view controller and pass date so i can change text of lable in another view.

Comment: Your question is too broad and too vague to answer. You probably want to implement the `UICollectionViewDelegate` method `collectionView(UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt: IndexPath)`. In that method you'd use the specified indexPath to fetch the appropriate item from your data model, then trigger a segue to the new view controller, or use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` to create and display a view controller directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

`SecondViewController` code:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController
{
    var date : NSDate!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dateLabel.text = date.description
    }
}
```

`FirstViewController` code:

Implement `didSelectItemAt:indexPath:` method of `UICollectionViewDelegate`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        let secondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
        secondVC.date = NSDate()
   self.navigationController.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
   }
```